# Accessing the MediaBuffer of the Audio File which is currently playing on the Android device

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I am able to access the media buffer of the file/stream through mediaextrator, mediacodec and audio track when I set the dataSource.

All I want is a method of accessing the media buffer of the audio which is playing through any music app in Android.

Comment: You want one app to access the audio data being played by a different app?

Comment: @fadden : Yes thats exactly what I wanted. To elaborate, I want to access the data in the media buffer of Android irrespective of the application which is playing the audio . Is it possible to achieve it at the application layer itself or do i have to go deeper into the kernel level using drivers ?

Comment: I suspect the easiest approach would be to replace the mediaserver component with your own. Apps are generally prevented from spying on or interfering with each other by the Linux permission systems. mediaserver is the gateway between apps and the media hardware drivers, so it's probably the best place.